# How to hide div with no ID in nested article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML layout I am trying to hide all the div's that dont have a ID attached to them.

- i know this question has been answered before on how to hide divs however when i try to use the answer given which is the Jquery below it doesnt work..

```js
$("div.(class-name):not([id])").hide();
```

```css
article div:before {content:attr(class);}/* added for visual */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="1806" class="post-1806">
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="fl-builder-content fl-builder-content-1806 fl-builder-content-primary" data-post-id="1806">
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-5cf7a50f62511" id="welcome">div</div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-2cf3a54f65511" id="welcome-2"></div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-2c2345511"></div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-2c5666535511"></div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-34534534511" id="hello"></div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
```

if i use the following code:

```js
$("div.fl-row:not([id])").hide();
```

```css
article div:before {content:attr(class);}/* added for visual */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="1806" class="post-1806">
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="fl-builder-content fl-builder-content-1806 fl-builder-content-primary" data-post-id="1806">
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-5cf7a50f62511" id="welcome">div</div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-2cf3a54f65511" id="welcome-2"></div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-2c2345511"></div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-2c5666535511"></div>
<div class="fl-row fl-row-full-width fl-row-bg-none fl-node-34534534511" id="hello"></div>
</div>
</div>
</article>
```

It hides all the elements in the whole page... I am using Wordpress however i believe this shouldn't matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dp7gn1qs/)

Comment: Check for errors in the console. This looks like wordpress html. Try `jQuery("div.(class-name):not([id])").hide();`

Comment: hello yes i do use jQuery not $ just all elements dissapear even if they have an ID or dont have an ID

Comment: @j08691 for some reason it is working on the site i am working on however it just hides 1 of the divs and not all...very weird would i need some sort of for each function?

Answer (score -1):

jQuery Solution;

```
$("div.my-awesome-class").each(function(){
var attr = $(this).attr('id');
    if (typeof attr == typeof undefined || attr == false) {
       $(this).hide();
    }
})
```